# Content script called by two different processes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a content script as part of my extension and every instruction in it is being called twice. This appears to be due to the script running in a VM while also executing in its own "context". I haven't explained it very well but the included screenshot should hopefully make it clear. Any thoughts on how to fix the issue would be much appreciated.

```
background page.js
--------------------------------------------------------------
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTabs[i], actions, function(response){console.log(response.txt);});
--------------------------------------------------------------

content script.js
--------------------------------------------------------------
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {

console.log("called");
var actions = msg; 

if(!actions.changed)
{
    return;
}   
if(actions.previous)
{
     previousBut.click();
}
if(actions.next)
{
    nextBut.click();
}
if(actions.playPause)
{
    pausePlayBut.click();
}
if(actions.shuffle)
{
    shuffleBut.click();
}
if(actions.repeat)
{
    repeatBut.click();
}
});
-----------------------------------------------------------

manifest
-----------------------------------------------------------
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["https://play.google.com/music/*"],
  "js": ["pageController.js"],
  "run_at": "document_start"
   }
   ]
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

[image: called pageController.js:6 called VM58:6]

Comment: Don't read too much in "VM". Can you show part of the relevant code? Are you using asynchronous methods and/or `eval`?

Comment: Hi here's the code that is effected, cheers James. [link](http://imgur.com/qgidf7I) @RobW

Comment: Could you put the relevant code in your question, in textual form? Don't forget the call to `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`, because that's also relevant.

Comment: How about the manifest file? (just the `"content_scripts"` part will do).

Comment: I have tried changing the '"run_at"' property in case you're wondering @RobW

Comment: I was suspecting that you're inserting the content script more than once per page (e.g. in a frame, but since you're not using `"all_frames": true`, that's not the cause. Are you calling `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` inside a `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` callback?

Comment: No `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` is called by a synchronous method, running on a timer every 250ms. @RobW

Comment: Well, then what's the problem? If you're running a timer with a frequency of 4 Hz, then you'll indeed see more than one `console.log` result. Please add all relevant details (context, code) to your question if you want a solution. In its current state, it cannot be solved.